# Does the downwash velocity calculation apply to hovering flight?

Tags: aircraft-performance

After reading a very interesting interplay between two writers attempting to answer [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/102556/what-is-the-downwash-speed-on-a-typical-helicopter) of helicopter downwash velocity, it occurred to me that, although this calculation:

> $V_i = \sqrt{\frac{F_n}{2 \rho S}}$

may be accurate, it would not take into account the vertical velocity of the air entering the disk.

When a helicopter is in a hovering state, is it not in its own vortex?  I am not sure if the helicopter pilot can compensate by adjusting the blade AoA to the relative wind of the downflow, but in forward flight blade AoA must be changed for forward and trailing wind components to keep lift constant on either side.

Does it take a lot more power to hover?  Can we predict the velocity of the **inflow** into the disk to determine the **outflow** velocity (which should be the inflow + the calculated downwash).

We would expect lower *net* downwash in forward flight, but how does that compare to power required in hovering flight?

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/45631/do-helicopters-use-more-fuel-when-hovering#:~:text=In%20both%20cases%2C%20the%20force,translational%20drag%20becomes%20an%20issue.

Comment: It seemed that agreeing to "split the difference" of two downwash velocity calculations required further examination.  Let's please keep working on this.

Comment: The power required for hover is plainly answered in the linked question. You may be able to rephrase your question but it needs more than just a title modification.

Comment: @Pilothead this question is about the formula applied for **downwash velocity** in the referenced question.  Why are you stuck on Power? (BTW, the reference provided by the moderators is *excellent*).  Why not take a try at an answer?

Comment: Because you are stuck on power. Your question contains "Does it take a lot more power to hover?" and "how does that compare to power required in hovering flight?". The answer to this is the question I put in the 'moderator's' link. Again, you need to do more than just modify the title.

Comment: @Pilothead is it good to be stubborn?  Please read the first paragraph and see what I am asking.  It is being suggested that **increased power** requirement (as evidenced by the fine reference) is required **because** the helicopter (in hover) is operating in its own downdraft **indicating** that this needs to be included in a **mathematical model** of predicted **net downwash**. (The two writers had the formula, 2x the formula, then split the difference).  While this type of. *diplomatic* agreement is understandable, does it have any place in science or (good) engineering?

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni, the induced velocity is a delta, so it's w.r.t to the incoming velocity, see for example this [link](http://www.aerodynamics4students.com/propulsion/blade-element-rotor-theory.php)

Comment: @ROIMaison Yes!  Hopefully others will read the link as well.